# ElasticSearch: How to specify a mapping using dynamic_templates for suggestions

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to create a completion mapping in ElasticSearch (version 2.3.4), using the dynamic_templates, so that later I can get suggestions for anything that looks like a "name" by hitting the myindex/_suggest uri.

Here is how I set it up:

```
curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "names": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "path_match": "*.name",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "completion":{
                  "type": "completion",
                  "analyzer": "standard",
                  "search_analyzer": "standard",
                  "payloads": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Here is what I have in ES (using elasticsearch-head plugin to look at contents):

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "mytype",
  "_id": "57b5123f3ca9d3ec007c285a",
  "_version": 2,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "foo": {
      "name": "bar",
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I query for on the _suggest uri:

```
{
    "foo_suggest" : {
        "text" : "bar",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "foo.name.completion"
        }
    }
}
```

What I get in response is an error saying "[foo.name.completion] is not a completion suggest field":

```
RemoteTransportException[[Gorgeous George][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/suggest[s]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Field [foo.name.completion] is not a completion suggest field];
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Field [foo.name.completion] is not a completion suggest field];
        at org.elasticsearch.action.suggest.TransportSuggestAction.shardOperation(TransportSuggestAction.java:152)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.suggest.TransportSuggestAction.shardOperation(TransportSuggestAction.java:61)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportBroadcastAction.java:282)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportBroadcastAction.java:278)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Field [name.completion] is not a completion suggest field]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggester.innerExecute(CompletionSuggester.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.completion.CompletionSuggester.innerExecute(CompletionSuggester.java:44)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggester.execute(Suggester.java:41)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.SuggestPhase.execute(SuggestPhase.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.suggest.TransportSuggestAction.shardOperation(TransportSuggestAction.java:147)
        ... 9 more
```

Am I way off? Am I doing something wrong/illegal? I do not get any error at index creation time - it only fails later when I try to hit the _suggest uri (and _search is working just fine).

Comment: Can you show how you index your document?

Comment: Added an edit of the original post, but here it is as well:
{
 "foo_suggest" : {
  "text" : "bar",
  "completion" : {
   "field" : "foo.name.completion"
  }
 }
}

Comment: That's a suggest query. Can you please show how you index your document first?

Comment: I am probably missing something... Isn't the creation of mapping creates the index.

Comment: I'm talking about the documents you add to your index, not the index itself.

Comment: Something like:

{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "mytype",
  "_id": "57b5123f3ca9d3ec007c285a",
  "_version": 2,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "name": "bar",
  }
}

Comment: You need to name your field `{"foo.name": "bar"}` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Sorry. Corrected the description. It is a nested document:
"_source": {
        "foo": {
          "name": "bar",
        }
      }

Comment: Please update your question with the mapping you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/myindex/_mypping/mytype`